# Outlook 2010 taskbar display which email account has an email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

My Acer, Win7 and Outlook 2010. I have several email accounts and want the Outlook taskbar icon to show me which account has the new email in. This would save me so much time as I have to open all the accounts to see which one has the email.

**Edit (copied from comments)**

I may not have made myself very clear. In the Task Bar I have several icons such as IE, Oulook, Notepad etc that are just 'One Click Opening'. When a email arrives a small yellow envelope appears bottom right of Outlook icon but does not indicate which email account the email resides in. I get the unread count showing next to the Inbox when I have the full viewing pane open and see the list of all my email accounts but I have to click on each account to see the folders that reside in it. Is there a way to see which one has an email without opening the Home email page

Comment: What have you tried or researched? Does your folder list show you an unread message count for each inbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outlook 2010 Navigation Pane - Show Unread Count on Mailbox](http://superuser.com/questions/399182/outlook-2010-navigation-pane-show-unread-count-on-mailbox) - you have to use the "favorites" feature.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I may not have made myself very clear. In the Task Bar I have several icons such as IE, Oulook, Notepad etc that are just 'One Click Opening'. When a email arrives a small yellow envelope appears bottom right of Outlook icon but does not indicate which email account the email resides in. I get the unread count showing next to the Inbox when I have the full viewing pane open and see the list of all my email accounts but I have to click on each account to see the folders that reside in it. Is there a way to see which one has an email without opening the Home email page.

Answer (score 0):

This may work as a work around but I can't test this sadly. I think it also depends on how many PST files you use... I *think* this only applies if you share the PST file for all the accounts.

Create a search folder which is done by clicking on the Folder tab, then clicking on New Search Folder

From within this select Unread mail

Click OK

You now have all of your unread email in a new folder (you may want to drag this to the Favourites).

Within this view (select Unread Mail), in the mail pane, add the field To and organise by Date

Then, when an email comes in, it will be at the top of this list and you can see at a glance who it is sent to... Of course, having it in this new folder means you may not even need to go to that account since you're already at the email... depends on your needs I guess

Please note, that when you select New Search Folder, there are quite a few options, including a Custom Search (at the bottom of the list) which may help...